# Using 2 views in 1 xib file

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2

I want to create a view that will appear only once (on first time). After, I want to show  another view.
Can I declare 2 views in 1 xib file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes but you you will need some funky looping code to extract the proper view or you could get the view via index, if you know it will always be at a given index. Personally this is not an ideal solution for me because I like to have strong pointers to all objects.

Your Could create a ViewController subclass with 2 views and then bind each view to variable via interface builder. This might be a little cleaner?

Answer (score 0):

You can, but there's no reason to do so.  Just use two separate view controllers, each with their own view (in separate nib files).